# what is name of soundtrack in Attack on Titan episode 18 arround around 19:50?

Tags: music, attack-on-titan

I started watching Attack on Titan and this soundtrack started playing  when the " Titans" showed up at Armin Arlert's group, around 19:51 of episode 18.
What soundtrack is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The music at this scene seems to be a variation of the second half of the song 凸】♀】♂】←巨人 : https://youtu.be/CVk770kdp3A?t=136 - the song from the OST contains some sound effects which are not heared in the scene itself.

Answer (score -2):

The songs name is probably '**Bad Karma**'

Comment: Actually, *both* songs used a sample from a pack called deepest india recorded in the 90s (according to [Axel Thesleff's tweet](https://twitter.com/AxelThesleff/status/1239656914050416642), the artist of Bad Karma himself)